# Upload image from smartphone to mobile website without mobile app?

Tags: file, mobile, upload, photo

I have a website where I want people to upload images of their pets from their smartphone. The problem is if this is possible? I mean "browse for image" perhaps only work for non-mobile units.

The goal is that the visitors can press "add image" and choose from their photo library on smartphone.

Facebook has this option on iphone, to upload images even if you enter facebook throgh Safari.
Does this need plugin? Where can i find info about this?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 6.0 and greater and Android 4.0 and greater both support the HTML 5 elements:

```
<input type='file'>
```

and

```
<input type='file' multiple='multiple'>
```

for single and multiple photo uploads respectively.